# How can I generate the DFA with following condition

Tags: automata

Give DFA's accepting the following languages over the alphabet$\{0,1\}$,The set of all strings such that each block of five consecutive symbols contains at least two 00s.
This question is from *Automata Theory,Languages, and Computation*.

I have tried to use 11 states but it's wrong obviously.
And I'm not sure about whether it's right to accept the strings that contain less than five symbols.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to use 11 states but it's wrong obviously.

Comment: And I'm not sure about whether it's right to accept the strings that contain less than five symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. It is easier to first compute a DFA for the complement of your language, which is the set of all words containing a block of five consecutive letters containing at most one $0$, that is, containing one of the following blocks: $11111, 01111, 10111, 11011, 11101, 11110$.
That is, the complement of your language is
$$
\{0,1\}^*(11111 \cup 01111 \cup 10111 \cup 11011 \cup 11101 \cup 11110)\{0,1\}^*
$$
Good luck to find the DFA, which has, if I am not wrong, 16 states.

P.S. To answer your last question, yes, words of length $< 5$ are in your language since they do not contain any block of length $5$.

Comment: It is a good idea to apply the closure of the complement operation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me a lot.